# Enviar datos de formulario POST desde el frontend a mi API de nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs

Cuando le doy al submit, la página entra en un blucle esperando respuesta hasta que se lanza el timeout.
La rutas han sido correctamente establecidas y el formulario situado en post. 
Lo datos son ingresados correctamente al enviarlos por POSTMAN.

Aquí el archivo .js con el método para registrar los datos.

```
MODIFICADO
```

El cual es llamado por:

```
MODIFICADO
```

---

### EDIT

Le agregué el body a la petición fetch, pero sigue sin funcionar, aquí el código:

HTML

```
<form action="http://xx.xx.205:3001/api/pedidos/registrar" method="POST" onsubmit="registrar(this)"></form>
```

---

```
async function registrar(data){
    data = $(data).serialize();
    const res = await fetch(`http://${ip}:${puerto}/api/pedidos/registrar`, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST"
    });
    const jsonData = await res.json();
    return jsonData.data;
}
```

---

### EDIT 2

He modificado un tanto el código en función de lo sugerido por Riven, a continuación adjunto la función que controla el registro/modificación

```
async function registrar(ev, data){
    ev.preventDefault();
    data = $(data).serialize();
    const string = $('form').attr('action').split('/')[5];
    if(string == 'registrar') action = 'POST';
    else if(string == 'modificar') action = 'PUT';
    const res = await fetch(`http://${ip}:${puerto}/api/pedidos/${string}`, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: `${action}`
    }); 
    const jsonData = await res.json();
    return jsonData;
}
```

Fragmento HTML:

```
<form action="http://138.197.205:3001/api/pedidos/registrar" method="POST" onsubmit="registrar(event, this)">
```

Comment: ¿Qué datos estás enviando? Falta `body` en el `fetch()`

Comment: Son varios, principalmente strings del body, a través de inputs, selects y textareas. 
Lo probaré de inmediato, suena como la solución inequívoca jajaja

Comment: Me refiero a que no estás enviando información `fetch('url', { header:{}, method:'POST', mode: 'CORS', body: datosEnviados })` te falta `body`

Comment: Hecho! Hice un edit al final, pues me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Adjunté el error en el edit

Comment: @JeanLouis estas colocando como method el action de tu form, debes colocar como method el method de tu form, el action siempre se encarga de la URL hacia donde quieres enviar la data, el method se encarga del tipo de peticion (GET o POST), en tu funcion registra estas modificando esos parametros erroneamente.

Comment: Sii, ya lo modifiqué. Sólo que se me modificaron algunos caracteres como los espacios y puntos (09%3A00 en vez e 09:30), así que tendré que recuperar los datos originales antes de guardar... Hay alguna forma de evitar que esto suceda?

Comment: @JeanLouis guardando el archivo con codificacion UTF-8 cerrando el archivo que tienes y abriendo el nuevo que tiene codificacion UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay unos cuantos errores, entre ellos:

- Recargas la pagina tu mismo al enviar la data
- usas el `await` de un `await`
- Por lo que se creo que no estas previniendo que la pagina se recargue (el formulario se envia).

Para lo primero deberas prevenir el envió de tu formulario (puesto que si lo envías por fetch entonces para que quisieras enviarlo también por el form?), así que lo que primero que debes hacer es en tu `HTML` acomodar la función de tal forma que envié el evento y el formulario, y no solo el formulario:

```
<form action="http://xx.xx.205:3001/api/pedidos/registrar" method="POST" onsubmit="registrar(event, this)"></form>
```

Lo segundo que debes hacer es prevenir que se envié el formulario, como había dicho previamente, ademas debes modificar la funcion para que ahora acepte dos paramentros (el evento y el formulario) entonces en la función `registrar` al inicio del todo prevenimos el envió del `form` con un `preventDefault`:

```js
async function registrar(ev, data){
    
    ev.preventDefault();
    data = $(data).serialize();
    const res = await fetch(`http://${ip}:${puerto}/api/pedidos/registrar`, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST"
    });
    const jsonData = await res.json();
    return jsonData.data;
}
```

Ademas de esto, he visto que en esta parte tienes un `location.reload` lo cual no es buena idea, puesto que su proposito no lo veo claro (para que recargar la pagina?), recargar la pagina no hara que la pagina te obtenga la data, por lo que deberas quitar:

```
location.reload();
```

al final de:

```
$('.registrar').click( async function() {
    $('form').attr({"action": "http://xx.xx.205:3001/api/pedidos/registrar", "method": "POST"});
    const ret4 = new Registro();
    const wath = await ret4.registrar();
    location.reload();
});
```

Para el error respecto al (usar `await` de un `await`) vi que lo corregiste en tu segunda edicion, por lo que no hondare al respecto puesto que ya lo haz solucionado.

Una cosa mas a tener en cuenta es que las claves y valores enviados por tu `body` en `fetch` van de acuerdo a el atributo `name` de los inputs que tengas dentro de tu `form`, donde el atributo `name` del input siempre hara referencia a la `key` del json, mientras que el atributo `value` hara referencia al valor del json a enviar.

**Deberás asegurarte que tus inputs tengan un name y corresponda con el nombre de dato que quieres tener en tu json.**

Si esto no funciona, asegurate de mirar que es lo que te devuelve el **backend** antes de hacer `res.json()`:

```
console.log(res);
const jsonData = await res.json();
```

Si el resultado no es un `JSON`, el error viene de parte del servidor, o estas enviando data incorrecta a este, y este te esta devolviendo un error.

De hecho ahora que me doy cuenta, y esto **es importante**:

Estas usando `serialize()` de `jQuery`, `serialize()` seria perfecto si estuvieses usando `$ajax` de `jQuery` ya que lo puedes usar directamente, pero para el caso de fetch, como se trata de una peticion `POST`, recuerda que las peticiones `POST` no reciben parametros tipo `urlFormEncoded` ya que eso es enrealidad lo que devuelve `serialize()` y por supuesto no puedes hacer `JSON.stringify()` a algo que directamente **NO** es un `JSON`.

asi que la solucion a ello es primero tratar de darle un formato tipo JSON a un `URLEncodedString`, por lo tanto:

```js
function encodedURLtoJSON(urlEncodedString){
   
   const fullValues = urlEncodedString.split("&");
   const keys = fullValues.map(el => el.split("=")[0]);
   const values = fullValues.map(el => el.split("=")[1]);
   const obj = {};

   for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
      obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
   }

   return obj;

}

const data = encodedURLtoJSON("name=Juan&edad=16&terminos=true");
console.log(data);
```

Ese ejemplo lo puedes aplicar a tu codigo, siendo que en esta parte, en vez de usar directamente `$(data).serialize();` deberas usar la nueva funcion para convertir ese `UrlFormEncoded` a un `Objeto` de Javascript:

```
data = encodedURLtoJSON($(data).serialize());
```

De esta manera al hacer `JSON.stringify` no obtendras el error.

Comment: Tremenda respuesta! Te escribo en seguida...